# In ASP.NET 5, how do I get the chosen route in middleware?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET 5 (vNext) site that will host dynamic pages, static content, and a REST Web API.  I have found examples of how to create middleware using the new ASP.NET way of doing things but I hit a snag.

I am trying write my own authentication middleware.  I would like to create a custom attribute to attach to the controller actions (or whole controllers) that specifies that it requires authentication.  Then during a request, in my middleware, I would like to cross reference the list of actions that require authentication with the action that applies to this current request.  It is my understanding that I configure my middleware before the MVC middleware so that it is called first in the pipeline.  I need to do this so the authentication is done before the request is handled by the MVC controller so that I can't prevent the controller from ever being called if necessary.  But doesn't this also mean that the MVC router hasn't determined my route yet?  It appears to me the determination of the route and the execution of that routes action happen at one step in the pipeline right?

If I want to be able to determine if a request matches a controller's action in a middleware pipeline step that happens before the request is handled by the controller, am I going to have to write my own url parser to figure that out?  Is there some way to get at the routing data for the request before it is actually handled by the controller?

Edit: I'm beginning to think that the [RouterMiddleware](https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/asp-net-5-routing-part-i/) might be the answer I'm looking for.  I'm assuming I can figure out how to have my router pick up the same routes that the standard MVC router is using (I use attribute routing) and have my router (really authenticator) mark the request as not handled when it succeeds authentication so that the default mvc router does the actual request handling.  I really don't want to fully implement all of what the MVC middleware is doing.  Working on trying to figure it out.  [RouterMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/RouterMiddleware.cs) kind of shows me what I need to do I think.

Edit 2: Here is a template for the middleware in ASP.NET 5

```
public class TokenAuthentication
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TokenAuthentication(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
             //do stuff here

             //let next thing in the pipeline go  
             await _next(context);

             //do exit code
        }
}
```

Comment: tbh I haven't looked into ASP.NET 5 but I assume it's similar if not the same re: routing in 5 as in 4. In 4 MVC doesn't do route handling per say. This is handled by the UrlRouting module which is a part of System.Web i.e. ASP.NET, not MVC. This is so routing can also be used in WebForms etc. So things like RouteTable / RouteData are ASP.NET concepts not MVC concepts and can therefore be accessed with out an MVC endpoint. MVC simply receives the routes once this module has determined that MVC is indeed the endpoint handler for the request i.e. that it is targeting an MVC endpoint route.

Comment: So you can get at Route data pre MVC, via RequestContext which has a RouteData and HttpContext properties. Now i realize much has changed with ASP.NET 5, and that System.Web is gone, but I'm assuming the modularity of URL routing hasn't been integrated into MVC and remains a separate concern that you can access pre-MVC or any other handling technology. Therefore your chicken and egg concern about MVC route determination should be moot. My question would therefore be "What is the ASP.NET 5 equivalent of a RequestContext"? as that is all your middleware should need to make a determination.

Comment: And that is probably just something like HttpContext.Request.RequestContext. Regardless of whether it's all new, the first thing that will be set up will be a context object of some sort with request/response properties which in turn will have their own contexts. `OWIN` for instance will create an `OwinContext` based off the environment tree and off that hang request/response properties with request paths etc. Again I haven;t had a look at 5 yet, but I'm sure the concepts wont be completely turned on their head.

Comment: Well with ASP.NET 5 they rewrote a lot of stuff.  For instance WebForms is not supported.  The RouteData is not on the RequestContext.  It looks like if I could get a hold on a RouteContext it has the RouteData as well as the HttpContext which has the RequestContext.

Comment: I added another edit showing how the middleware is setup.  You don't inherit from anything, but the convention is you have an Invoke method with that signature.  Then you create an extension class that adds a "UseMyMiddleware" method to IApplicationBuilder. That HttpContext does not have access to the route data as far as I can tell.  It is not on the RequestContext which is a property on HttpContext.

Comment: As far as modularity it is a little fuzzy time me what is going on.  It looks like you can let MVC do the routing using the MVC middleware or you can take more control and use the Routing middleware.  What ever is called first in the Startup class's Configure method comes first in the request pipeline.  So it looks like if you put a custom routing middleware like I linked above before the MVC middleware, if your routing middleware said that it handled the request the MVC middleware would ignore it.  I'm wondering if I can setup a routing middleware that uses same routings but doesn't handle it

Comment: Yep thats OWIN chaining. You can setup your middle as what might have been called an HttpModule via the app.use, when you want a handler you would use app.Run.

Comment: Check out this url http://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/

Answer (score 3):

I ended up looking through the ASP.NET source code (because it is open source now!) and found that I could copy the UseMvc extension method from [this class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) and swap out the default handler for my own.

```
public static class TokenAuthenticationExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseTokenAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
    {
        var routes = new RouteBuilder
        {
            DefaultHandler = new TokenRouteHandler(),
            ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices
        };

        configureRoutes(routes);

        routes.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(
            routes.DefaultHandler,
            app.ApplicationServices));

        return app.UseRouter(routes.Build());
    }
}
```

Then you create your own version of [this class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/MvcRouteHandler.cs).  In my case I don't actually want to invoke the actions.  I will let the typical Mvc middleware do that.  Since that is the case I gut all the related code and kept just what I needed to get the route data which is in **actionDescriptor** variable.  I probably can remove the code dealing with backing up the route data since I dont think what I will be doing will affect the data, but I have kept it in the example.  This is the skeleton of what I will start with based on the mvc route handler.

```
public class TokenRouteHandler : IRouter
{
    private IActionSelector _actionSelector;

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        EnsureServices(context.Context);

        context.IsBound = _actionSelector.HasValidAction(context);

        return null;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var services = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;

        EnsureServices(context.HttpContext);

        var actionDescriptor = await _actionSelector.SelectAsync(context);
        if (actionDescriptor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var oldRouteData = context.RouteData;
        var newRouteData = new RouteData(oldRouteData);

        if (actionDescriptor.RouteValueDefaults != null)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in actionDescriptor.RouteValueDefaults)
            {
                if (!newRouteData.Values.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                {
                    newRouteData.Values.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            context.RouteData = newRouteData;

            //Authentication code will go here  <-----------
            var authenticated = true;

            if (!authenticated)
            {
                context.IsHandled = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!context.IsHandled)
            {
                context.RouteData = oldRouteData;
            }
        }
    }

    private void EnsureServices(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (_actionSelector == null)
        {
            _actionSelector = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionSelector>();
        }            
    }
}
```

And finally, in the Startup.cs file's Configure method at the end of the pipeline I have it setup so that I use the same routing setup (I use attribute routing) for the both my token authentication and mvc router.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //Other middleware delcartions here <----------------

        Action<IRouteBuilder> routeBuilder = routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        };

        app.UseTokenAuthentication(routeBuilder);

        //Middleware after this point will be blocked if authentication fails by having the TokenRouteHandler setting context.IsHandled to true

        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder);
    }
```

Edit 1:
I should also note that at the moment I am not concerned about the extra time required to select the route twice which is what I think would happen here since both my middleware and the Mvc middleware will be doing that.  If that becomes a performance problem then I will build the mvc and authentication in to one handler.  That would be best idea performance-wise, but what I have shown here is the most modular approach I think.

Edit 2:
In the end to get the information I needed I had to cast the ActionDescriptor to a ControllerActionDescriptor.  I am not sure what other types of actions you can have in ASP.NET but I am pretty sure all my action descriptors should be ControllerActionDescriptors.  Maybe the old legacy Web Api stuff needs another type of ActionDescriptor.